# CSS-only sliding underline tabs

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

We had a set of tabs in our Bootstrap3-based site, which worked fine.  We had this scss mixin which would

1. calculate the number of tabs being used based on the class you applied to the nav
2. put an ::after pseudo-element below the last-child `li` to make an "underline" the width of the `li` with a transition on `translateX` and a `translateX` of 0
3. when a given `li` got a class of `active` applied to it by Bootstrap, translate the `::after` element on the last-child the correct percentage to slide it underneath the active tab

So, now updating to Bootstrap 4.1, I discovered that it no longer applies the `active` class to the `li`, but to the `a` tag within it.  So my sibling selector no longer works:

```
.tabs-sliding li:nth-child(2).active ~ li:last-child::after {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}
```

I realize I could do this with javascript, but I'm still hoping for a scss-only solution.  [Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/xaQjdy?editors=1100) with the entire code.  The pink background when a tab is clicked was just a text to confirm the `active` class.

Here is the mixin (also in the codepen):

```
@mixin sliding-tabs($tab-number) {
  $children: $tab-number;
  //percentage function converts 1 to 100
  $width: percentage(1 / $children);

  //apply width to .nav-tabs li & a tags
  &.tabs-sliding .nav.nav-tabs li {
    width: $width;
  }

  //based on width of each tab, figure out the appropriate offset for the sliding ::after pseudo-element "underline"
  @for $i from 1 through $children {
    li:nth-child(#{$i}) a.active {
      background-color: pink !important;
    }
    li:nth-child(#{$i}) a.active ~ li:last-child::after {
      $offset: percentage($i - $children);
      transform: translateX(#{$offset});
    }
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
.tabs-sliding {
  @include sliding-tabs(5);
}
```